# Deployed debug Gnosis Safe Guard example can't be added to my Gnosis Safe Wallet

Tags: gnosis-safe

I deployed the Gnosis Safe Guard example (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/contracts/examples/guards/DebugTransactionGuard.sol) on rinkeby network using remix.

Then I followed the official guide to add it to my gnosis wallet:
https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5496893-add-a-transaction-guard

After confirm the transaction on gnosis UI, it just fails with revoke message on the blockchain. No more clues. I'm wondering if there is an issue on the Gnosis app itself, or I'm missing something?

Details: My wallet created on rinkedby has balance and transaction was confirmed by the 2 owners.

Comment: The transaction failed on rinkeby is 0x5cc96dca908986b2b89f686c3b9d4f07e79bcefb217b92bdf4fbeff1b35c525e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safe's transaction recipient is  `0xd9Db270c1B5E3Bd161E8c8503c55cEABeE709552` (singleton) but it should be `0x784b9e48eb29b1dd4956aed7385e9c99444306cd` (safe proxy) instead